# google translation

Tags: google-translate

```
function translate(lang) {
   var source = document.getElementById("article").innerHTML;
   var len = source.length;

   // Google Language API accepts 500 characters per request 
   var words = 500;
    document.getElementById("translation").style.display='block';

    document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML = ""; 

   for(i=0; i<=(len/words); i++) {
     google.language.translate (source.substr(i*words, words),
                 "en", lang, function (result) {
        if (!result.error) {
            document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += result.translation;
        } }); }  

  // Hide the text written in the original language
    document.getElementById("article").style.display = 'none';
    return false;
}
```

Normally, the translation alright. After attempting couple of click, the translated page is not in correct order.  For example, the page:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<ul>
  <li>list 1</li>
  <li>list 2</li>
  <li>list 3</li>
</ul>
```

output:

```
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<ul>
  <li>list 1</li>
  <li>list 2</li>
  <li>list 3</li>
</ul>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee the order that the translation responses are going to come back to you.

You would have the same problem making any other kind of AJAX request as well.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  Do you have any idea how to solve this kind of problem?